# Convert standard image file format to py4DSTEM datacube?

Tags: python, software-assistance, electron-diffraction

I want to analyze a diffraction pattern. Py4dSTEM is asking for a datacube to start with. I thought it might be able to convert an image to this format:

`py4DSTEM.io.read('tinicu.png')`

But I get this error:

```
Exception: Unrecognized file extension .png.  To force reading as a particular filetype, pass the 'ft' keyword argument.
```

Since py4DSTEM doesn't seem to work directly with images, is there any software that can convert say a png (or any other common image format) to their datacube format?

Then I tried:
`py4DSTEM.io.read('tinicu.png', ft='None')`

And I get this error:

````
  if binfactor > 1:
     86         assert(mem!='MEMMAP'), "Error: binning is not supported for memory mapping.  Either set binfactor=1 or set mem='RAM'"
---> 87     assert(ft in [None,'dm','empad','mrc_relativity','gatan_K2_bin','kitware_counted']), "Error: ft argument not recognized"
     88 
     89     if ft is None:

AssertionError: Error: ft argument not recognized
```
````

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe this program can read in data from a PNG? All the examples and documentation on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/py4dstem/py4DSTEM) seem to suggest that it requires very specialized files.

Comment: Thanks Tyberius, yep, it does not accept .png.  I was thinking it might be useful for analyzing diffraction patterns and so would accept most standard image formats.  It still might be useful by using a different library to read in .png then convert to a py4DSTEM object like a DiffractionSlice depending on what analysis I want to do.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation of py4dstem](https://py4dstem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4dstem.html)? As the name suggests, it specializes in analyzing 4d STEM data. I don't think it will be convenient for analyzing regular 2d STEM images.

Comment: @leopold.talirz Yes, thanks.  I had assumed analyzing a 2D image would be a part of analyzing a 4D dataset, and I could use that.  However, it doesn't read in a 2D image as a default option.

Comment: Why is your account unregistered? I was considering to add a 50-point bounty to this question, but with an unregistered account, I'm not even sure if you'll see the answer if I were to do that.